# Large messages failing on Stomp Controller in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, stomp

I have a stomp controller in a spring boot application, When ever i send a message which exceeds 256kb it fails to enter the controller. I don't see any error messages. Is there any setting where I can configure it to allow larger messages.

Here is my controller

```
@Component
@Controller
public class DiscussionController {
    @MessageMapping("/discussion")
    public void post(DiscussionMessage message) {

    }
}
```

Here is my config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("ngdesk");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ngdesk-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the [web-socket transport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketTransportRegistration.html), e.g.:

```
@Override 
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
   registration.setMessageSizeLimit(512 * 1024); // 512K
}
```